# Are reader-centric questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

*Perhaps this is a strange discussion asked on a site for **writers**, but...*

Are questions that are asked from **the reader's perspective** on-topic?

Example excerpt:

> I've just read [Is it better to slowly introduce a character's looks rather than describing it all in one paragraph?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/66150/is-it-better-to-slowly-introduce-a-characters-looks-rather-than-describing-it-a) and its answers. As a visual person, I often try to imagine the story visually, like creating a comic/animation inside my head. I often had trouble when imagining a scene if the person lacks the detail of the appearance (and sometimes also the personality, depending on the situation). Are there some hints to make the visualization goes smoothly/not often interrupted due to the lack of details?

(The example might not be a good question due to probably being opinion-based/too broad, but the concept is there)

I think the closest discussion that talks about "reader" is ["Readers" and "audience" tags](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1865/readers-and-audience-tags), which is talking about the readers and audience, but still from the writer's perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example question. Is it correct that you ask how as a reader you can better visualize what you read? Then that question would be off topic, in my opinion.

Comment: @user52445 yes, you interpret it correctly. Please post it as an answer so that the community can vote it accordingly, preferably with clear arguments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to see how the given example would be on-topic, I can think of "reader" questions that *would* be on on topic in so far as it being in service of Writing e.g. questions around reading in order to analyse/learn from the writing in it, or questions around being a beta-reader for a writer.